# Can Retrofit2 be use on Android 4.1.2? My app results in fatal exception caused by Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

Is there a way to use Retrofit2 on older Android versions (for me a minimum of 4.x)?

My app works as expected on Android 6, but I get a fatal exception on Android 4.1.2:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:628)
        at com.example.temperaturemonitor.RESTApi.getClient(RESTApi.java:15)
```

This is the code causing the error (.build is RESTApi.java:15):

```
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.10:5001/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
```

I can see that the root cause of the error appears to be okhttp3.

In build.gradle I have

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
```

I found at https://developer.squareup.com/blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5/ that "OkHttp 3.13 Requires Android 5+". They are also maintaining 3.12 of okhttp which is Android 4.x compatible. What is not clear to me is what version of okhttp is used by Retrofit2 (I have no implementation line importing okhttp directly into to my project); my assumption is that they are using the latest version.

I would like to be able to use both my Android phones with the app once complete (and if I decide to release into the App store then including earlier versions increases the potential users). I realise that might prevent me from using some newer code features, but I can probably live with that - up to now nothing I've tried has not been possible on both versions.

My thought is that perhaps if I could make Retrofit use the okhttp3.12 library then the error would not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses version `3.14.9` of `okhttp`. You can see that in the [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/build.gradle) file. Additionally, you could use the command `gradlew app:dependencies`. You should see something as follows in the output of that command:

```
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.2
```

If you want to force it to use version `3.12.0` of `okhttp`, adding the following seems to work:

```
implementation ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0') {
    force = true
}
```

Comment: Android Studio (4.0) reports force is deprecated but it still works

Comment: @PeteC I am using Android Studio 3.6.3 and it's not complaining. Anyways, good to know that it worked.